# Drawing to an existing image with X-window

Tags: linux, graphics, x11, xlib

I am using X-window (X11) to render 2D graphics (lines, circles, text...). But rather than drawing to a window, I need to draw to an existing bitmap image. Is there a way to achieve this ? If yes, are there restrictions on the bitmap format ?

(Notice: I am not trying to render an image to a window.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a pixmap via: [XCreatePixmap](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/pixmap-and-cursor/XCreatePixmap.html)
- Create a context via [XCreateGC](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/GC/XCreateGC.html), specifying the pixmap as the drawable.
- Transfer the contents of your existing image via [XPutImage](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/XPutImage.html) (see also [Transferring Images between Client and Server](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/images.html)), specifying the pixmap as the drawable and the related context.
- do your renderings via [GC Convenience Routines](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/GC/convenience-functions/) and [Graphics Functions](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/)
- Get the contents from the pixmap via: [XGetImage](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/XGetImage.html), see also [Transferring Images between Client and Server](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/images.html)
- Save the image data.

Comment: I finally managed to solve this (at least partially), though fiddling with the bitmap formats was a little nightmarish. In particular, I had to discover by experimentation that 24 bits RGB was stored on 32 bits. The creation of a suitable XImage to be used with XPutImage is particularly difficult.